# Android maps not showing on deployed app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

HELP PLEASE - I've followed all the instructions I can find, hopefully accurately, but my deployed App isn't showing any maps, just a grey background (BUT WORKS ON EMULATOR AND DEVICES WITH DEBUG GENERATED KEY). It's someone else's App that I've taken over and updated, and have their release keystore, alias and passwords.

Using the release keystore SHA1 number I've created a new API release key following the [Get API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en) page, using their release certificate tab instructions. I have added this key to the google_maps_api.xml.

I've added all the necessary permissions I think I need (manifest below) but no joy. The rest of the App works fine, so I know the release keystore is valid as Google Play lets me deploy my updates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.HurryHereNow.HHN">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name="com.HurryHereNow.HHN.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.HurryHereNow.HHN.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.HurryHereNow.HHN.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.HurryHereNow.HHN.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.HurryHereNow.HHN.Search"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing, or have done, wrong? I repeat it all worked fine with debug api key on emulator and devices.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: build.gradle included

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.HurryHereNow.HHN"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    // This needs updating every release deployment
    versionCode 3
    // This needs updating every release deployment
    versionName "2.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: how are you deploying your app ? by generating apk ? what keystore you are using for generating apk is that signed apk ?

Comment: Using Android Studio, Build > Generate Signed APK, and using the keystore provided by previous developer. Then deploying as usual via dev console, updating APK.

Comment: you need to generate SHA1 from the keystore provided by previous developer. It is currenly expecting KEY from previous KEYSTORE but you provided of the DEBUG keystore

Comment: How can you tell that? I used keytool -list to get the SHA1 from the keystore, so not using the debug code. I now have two map keys for this package, one release and one debug, and I comment out/in appropriate when I generate signed APK.

Comment: Are you saying, you are using SHA1 of the keystore provided from the previous developer ? if yes then go to console.google.com and check if MAY API is enabled using the acc which is used in generating the API key

Comment: Yes, the maps_android_backend api is enabled already.

Comment: Ta for help, you pointed me in right direction - two google_maps_api.xml files and forgot to update release one! New for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be annoying, but these are the general steps I've taken when debugging Google API issues with my apps:

1. Check the logcat while running your deployed app. The Google Maps library is very good about informing you when there's a key mismatch or other problem that's preventing access to the API.
2. Check your Google Developers Console and cross reference the key signatures AS WELL AS the package names. They both must match your released app. You may need to add more entries.
3. Check your manifest for the right key and/or any other stray google maps v2 keys that might be overriding each other.

Comment: I'll have a go at getting logcat. Pretty sure I've cross references everything correctly.

Comment: Couple of warnings. Any use?
01-12 13:30:58.219 2067-6194/? W/ctxmgr: [ContextSpecificAclFactory]LocationConsent failed, ULR opt-in status is: false, account=account#1811372864#
01-12 13:30:58.220 2067-6194/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]checkPermissionTypeStatus: no write permission for { uid=10003, packageName=com.google.android.gms }. Returned permission was: USER_CONSENT_REQUIRED for context name=USER_LOCATION, account=account#1811372864#

Comment: Thank - think I cracked it. Forgot to add new key to app/src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml, hope this sorted now.